# facebook developer authenticate instagram test user

Tags: facebook, authorization, instagram

I'm trying to display my instagram feed on my website. I'm going through the facebook developer tutorial here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started

I'm not understanding step 4: authenticate the test user. When it says construct the authorization window url, does that mean create a web page with the:

```
  https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
  ?client_id={app-id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
  &scope=user_profile,user_media
  &response_type=code
```

Is that supposed to be in a javascript or what?

Comment: It isn't supposed to be "in" any particular language - _how_ you create that URL, is up to you. The important part is that you must redirect the user to that URL, so that they can grant your app the permissions.

Comment: I guess this isn't what I want then. I don't want to display users instagram feed on the site. I just want to display my instagram feed on my website.

Comment: Then _you_ still need to grant the app permission to read _your_ posts.